# Is there a PC software to manage a dedicated server

Tags: dedicated-server

I have a dedicated server running "debian GNU/linux" and i want a cpanel like which is a pc software based, so i can manage the server without a browser.

Maybe some software use SSH to process the queries or something like that.

i should be able to manage pop3 emails and mysql databases and so on....

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the point of using SSH queries? Security? Then use SSL on your web connections. Any other program is just mimicking a web server-client model, and introducing more points of security holes onto the server.

Use already good code that works, use it securely and intelligently.

Otherwise, learn the commands yourself and use ssh via putty remotely.

Comment: +1 for "learn the commands".